# IOError: [Errno 0] Error in Python

Tags: python, file-io, io

I use Windows 7.

```
myfile = open("matedata.txt", "a+")
print myfile.readline()
myfile.write("1")
myfile.close()
```

And this doesn't work.

```
myfile.write("1")
IOError: [Errno 0] Error
```

Comment: How come i can't edit my post? Myfile is an empty file. myfile.readline() returns "nothing"

Comment: What happens if you change it to a file that doesn't exist?

Comment: What happens if you do not read from this file - just write?

Comment: This is probably unrelated to your error, but you should use a [`with` statement](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) to handle your open file, rather than explicitly closing it.

Comment: You're running windows, you opened the file in `a+` mode, and did a read operation before a write operation.  This makes windows unhappy for whatever reason.  I remember there being a workaround if you really need to do this, but really just don't read and write in `a+` mode.

Comment: @roippi the possible dupe answer has the workaround in

Comment: Yes it might be a duplicate, but i didn't find it, i was searching with the exact error "IOError: [Errno 0] Error" and didn't  found it.

Comment: Anyway seek didn't work. I remove readline() and it worked! But I added it again and it still worked. So I think in the file, there must be something written to use readline() function!

Answer (score -2):

When you open a file with python, you need to specify the type of access you want (read, write or append):

- a - for appending
- r - for reading
- w - for writing

the '+' means update/create new if doesn't exists.

you getting IOError because you open file and you try to do both reading and writing with the same FD(file discreptor)

Comment: Incorrect.  Reading and writing is possible with the same file.  See the documentation (http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open), which says that `+` does not mean to create a file, but instead it means to open a file for both reading and writing.

Comment: In addition to what Dietrich Epp said, if the file doesn't exists, 'w' mode will create it, no need for the use of '+'.